# Membership based on maximum of a function over the set.

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f(x)$ be a continuous function over $\mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore, define $s_{\text{max}}:= \sup_{x\in S} \{f(x)\}$ and let $f(x)$ attain its minimum for at least one element in $S$.

Under what conditions on $f(x)$ and $S$ does it hold that $f(x_1)\leq s_{\text{max}}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_1\in S$?

In particular, does this hold if $f(x)$ is a convex function and $S$ is a convex set? If $f(x)$ is convex and $S$ is an arbitrary set?

Unfortunately I am far from my comfort zone here, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean $f(x) < s_{max} \implies x \in S$ or $f(x) < s_{max} \Leftrightarrow x \in S$? In the latter case, no such function exists as then $x_{max} \notin S$ and in the former, for any set any constant function works. You might have wanted $\leq$ instead. Also, some sets don't have a $\max$, you might want to use $\sup$ instead.

Comment: I am only interested in $f(x)\leq s_{max} \Rightarrow x\in S$. Thanks for your comments, I have amended the question based on them. Yes, a constant function would work but I would like to know what other possibilities are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Sigma_S = \{x | f(x) \leq \sup_{t \in S} f(t) \}$. If $x \in S$, then we have $f(x) \leq \sup_{t \in S} f(t)$, hence $x \in \Sigma_S$, i.e, $S \subset \Sigma_S$. This is true for all $S,f$.

The desired property above is equivalent to $\Sigma_S \subset S$, hence this is true iff $S = \Sigma_S$.

That is, the property you desire is true iff $S$ has the form $\{x | f(x) \leq L \}$ for some $L$ (which may be $\infty$).

For a counterexample, choose the convex function $f(x) = x^2$ on the convex set $[0,1]$. It is easy to see that $s_\max =1$, but $f(-1) \leq 1$ also.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that $S$ is a subset of the domain of $f$ which -- for the case of maximisation -- we define as $\operatorname{dom}f=\{x|f(x)>-\infty\}$. Then, the fact that $f(x)\leq s_{max}$ does not imply that $x\in S$ nor that $x\notin S$. You can see this through a simple example. Consider the concave function $f(x)=-x^2$ and the convex set $S=[-1,1]$. Then $s_{max}=\sup_{-1\leq x \leq 1}-x^2=0$ and take $x_0=2\notin S$. Notice that $f(x_0)\leq s_{max}$. You can easily find counter-examples for your statement using convex functions. Take for instance the convex function $f(x)=x^2$ and $S=[1,2]$ and $x_0=0$.

One useful things about convex *minimisation* over *convex* sets, is that any local minimum you find is also global. The same holds true for maximisation problems when the function is *concave* and the set *convex*.

I can only think of an extremely special case where your statement holds true. $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is quadratic, i.e. $f(x)=x'Qx$ for some positive definite matrix $Q$, and $S$ is of the form $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|x'Px\leq \gamma\}$ for some $\gamma>0$ and $P=P'$ positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try answering the following question. What kind of set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ can be defined as $\{x|f(x) \leq c\}$ for a continuous $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and constant $c$.

Trivially, the function $f(x) = \inf_{y \in S} d(x, y)$ - distance from $S$ to $x$ defines any closed set $S$. In general the shape of $f$ can vary a lot as long as $f(\partial S) = c$ and $f$ has the right relation to $c$ in the interior and exterior of $S$. Open sets would work if the condition was $f(x) < c$. Now $f$ would measure the (negative of) distance from $x$ to the complement of $S$ instead.

This does not cover all sets though. $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$, for example is neither closed nor open. It is clear that unless $f(\mathbb{Q}) = c$ the function will not be continuous. Now take any Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ that does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}$. Due to continuity of $f$ we have that $f(\lim x_n) = \lim f(x_n) = \lim c = c$ - a contradiction.